# How do I turn on VSync and other advanced settings in Dead Island?

Tags: dead-island

I can't stand screen tearing and I'm wondering how I can turn on vertical sync. There doesn't seem to be on option to turn it on through the game itself. Where can I find the file to turn it on? Are there other settings I can adjust that aren't available ingame? I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Use Dead Island Helper

If you do not feel comfortable editing files by hand, you can use [Dead Island Helper](http://www.theplaywrite.com/tools-and-utilities/dead-island-helper-automatically-improve-performance-and-apply-tweaks-without-having-to-edit-files/), a program which will do this for you. According to the creator, it does install a keyboard hook to detect if Dead Island is running, but only to prevent multiple keystrokes from being processed. It *shouldn't* trigger VAC, but you have to decide for yourself if you want to run the risk.

If you'd rather edit files yourself, you can follow the steps outlined below:

### Turning on VSync

- Navigate to `My Documents\Dead Island\out\Settings`

Here, you'll find a files named `Video.scr` Windows 7 will recognize this file as a screensaver file, so you need to open it with a file editor such as Notepad. You can do this by dragging and dropping the Video.scr file to Notepad or using Notepad and navigating to the directory. Remember to change the dropdown to look for "All files" if you do this.

Upon opening the file, you will find something that looks like this:

```
!Resolution(i,i)
!WindowOffset(i,i)
!Monitor(i) // -1 primary monitor
!BPP(i)
!FSAA(i) // Full Screen AntiAliasing, 0 - none, higher is better
!TexBPP(i)
!TextureQuality(s) // VeryLow, Low, High
!Filtering(s) // Bilinear, Trilinear, Anisotropic, AnisotropicTrilinear
!GammaFloat(f)
!MaxRefresh(i)
!Shadows(s) // Low, High
!ShadowMapSize(i)
!SpotShadowMapSize(i)
!Lightmaps()
!Fullscreen()
!VSync() // enable vertical sync
!MaterialQuality(i) // lower is better
!WaterQuality(i) // lower is better
!GrassQuality(i) // lower is better
!FXQuality(i) // higher is better
!FXFadeLevel(i) // 0-4 (lower is better)
!EnvQuality(s) // FullDynamic, RareDynamic, Static
!ShaderPath(i) // 0 - 1.1, 1 - 1.4, 2 - 2.0, 3 - 3.0, 4 - x360, 5 - 4.0, 6 - ps3
!PostProcess(s) // Simple, Normal
!DisplayDeviceType(i,f,f,f,f) //device type (LCD TV etc.): 0 - default
!Curves(s) // curves texure

Resolution(1920,1080)
Monitor(0)
BPP(24)
FSAA(0)
TexBPP(32)
TextureQuality("High")
Filtering("Trilinear")
Fullscreen()
Shadows("High")
ShadowMapSize(1024)
SpotShadowMapSize(1024)
Lightmaps()
GammaFloat(1.00)
MaxRefresh(60)
MaterialQuality(2)
FXQuality(3)
FXFadeLevel(2)
WaterQuality(2)
GrassQuality(0)
EnvQuality("FullDynamic")
ShaderPath(3)
DisplayDeviceType(0,0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.0 00000)
```

These are the default values that the game is using. If you want to enable Vertical Sync, insert `VSync()` between the values of `Fullscreen()` and `Shadows("High")` like so:

```
Fullscreen()
VSync()
Shadows("High")
```

Remember that if you want this to work properly, you need to have refresh rate set to the same value as your monitor's refresh rate. That variable is:

```
MaxRefresh(60)
```

After making this adjustment, click **Save** and exit. It is currently under dispute whether or not you need to set this file as **Read-only** or not, as some people say that you need to, otherwise the game will overwrite your settings and others say that it will only overwrite *invalid* settings. I did not need to until I changed my Post Processing settings, which didn't seem to take until I set it as Read-only. If you want to play it safe, you can set it by doing the following:

- Rightclick the `Video.scr` file
- Select `Properties`
- On the `General` tab you'll see `Attributes` near the bottom
- Check `Read-only` box and click `Apply` then `OK`

### Increasing the graphical quality

Even after setting the ingame options to "High," there's still more you can do to increase the graphical quality. You can adjust other attributes in this file if you are comfortable doing so and know what your video card and system can handle.

If you choose to adjust these individual settings, I would advise only changing one variable at a time so you know what to change back in case of crashing (if you have it set as "Read-only" at least, *theoretically* it should change any invalid values automatically if it doesn't).

**Increase color quality**

```
BPP(24)
```

Change this setting to `32`. And in conjunction with this make sure you:

**Enable Post Processing**

```
PostProcess("Normal")
```

Add this line, it doesn't seem to matter where you put it.

**Enable FSAA (Fullscreen Anti-Aliasing)**

```
FSAA(0)
```

Change the `0` to either `2`,`4`, `8`, or `16`.

**Increase environmental detail settings**

```
MaterialQuality(2)
FXFadeLevel(2)
WaterQuality(2)
GrassQuality(0)
```

Make sure all of these are set to `0`.

**Increase the texture quality**

```
Filtering("Trilinear")
```

Change `Trilinear` to `Anisotropic` or `AnisotropicTrilinear`.

**Increase shadow quality**

```
ShadowMapSize(1024)
SpotShadowMapSize(1024)
```

Change `1024` to either `2048` or `4096`. *Note that changing these settings may cause crashing*. I was succesfully able to change SpotShadowMapSize to 4096, however I could only increase ShadowMapSize to 2048 without crashing. As stated, make sure you change variables individually to be able to pinpoint crash causes.

### Example setup

I'm running an ATi Radeon HD 4890 1GB card on a system with 12GB RAM and my settings are as follows:

```
Resolution(1920,1080)
Monitor(0)
BPP(32)
FSAA(16)
TexBPP(32)
TextureQuality("High")
Filtering("AnisotropicTrilinear")
Fullscreen()
Shadows("High")
ShadowMapSize(2048)
SpotShadowMapSize(4096)
Lightmaps()
GammaFloat(1.35)
MaxRefresh(60)
MaterialQuality(0)
FXQuality(3)
FXFadeLevel(0)
WaterQuality(0)
GrassQuality(0)
EnvQuality("FullDynamic")
ShaderPath(5)
VSync()
PostProcess("Normal")
DisplayDeviceType(0,0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000)
```

~Sources: [This thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2101237) and [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=24894309#post24894309) on the Steam forums

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple workaround to enable VSync in Dead Island.

- Navigate to `"Documents\DeadIsland\out\Settings"`
- Find and open the file `"video"` with in a text editor like notepad.
- Find the line where `"Fullscreen()"` is written.
- Add `"VSync()"` on a new line under `"Fullscreen()"`

Note: If this do not work, you might have to edit permissions on the file to read-only, since the game can edit the file to change what you added.

- Right click the file and click `"option"s`
- Mark the box called `"Read-only"` under the `"Attributes"` tag.

Answer (score 2):

A video guide going step by step with some of the same information for those that take in information easier by watching instead of reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/category/rivatuner/) and use D3DOverrider (which comes with it) to fix screen tearing in game.