# Is it possible to change the Field of View (FOV) in Dead Island?

Tags: dead-island

The default Field of View in Dead Island is quite cramped, and even though I'm not prone to motion sickness, I tend to get a headache when I play the game as a result. I went through the options, but there doesn't seem to be any way to adjust the FOV. Is there a workaround or a solution that would let me fix the FOV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not feel comfortable editing files by hand, you can use [Dead Island Helper](http://www.theplaywrite.com/tools-and-utilities/dead-island-helper-automatically-improve-performance-and-apply-tweaks-without-having-to-edit-files/), a program which will fix the FOV issue as well as [other advanced settings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29950/how-do-i-turn-on-vsync-and-other-advanced-settings-in-dead-island).

According to the creator, it does install a keyboard hook to detect if Dead Island is running, but only to prevent multiple keystrokes from being processed. It *shouldn't* trigger VAC, but you have to decide for yourself if you want to run the risk.

If you'd rather edit files yourself, you can follow the steps outlined below:

1. Navigate to the Data folder in your Dead Island installation. This
   will vary based on whether you installed through Steam or put it in
   an install folder of your choice. In Steam, by default it is located
   here in `\Steam\steamapps\common\dead island\DI\`
2. Locate the `Data0.pak` file and open it with a file archiving
   program such as [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) or
   [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).
3. Inside `Data0.pak` you'll see a folder called `Data` and inside
   `Data`, you will find the `Skills' folder.
4. Inside the `Skills` folder, locate the file `default_levels.xml`
5. Now that you have found this file, navigate to `My Documents\DeadIsland\out`
6. Inside the `out` folder, you're going to want to recreate the directory structure of where the XML files was located. Do this by creating a New Folder, name it `Data`, then inside that folder, create another New Folder and name this one `Skills`.
7. Copy/Paste the `default_levels.xml` folder from the archive into the `Skills` folder. You can close your archiving program after this, as you wno't need it anymore.
8. After pasting the `default_levels.xml` file, open it with a text editor such as Notepad.
9. Locate the variable `CameraDefaultFOV`. You can do this by using ctrl+F. You'll see `v+"62.5"` as the default value. Change this so something between 70 and 90, based on your preference.
10. **Save** the file and exit. You may want to set it as "Read-only" like it's recommended in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29950/how-do-i-turn-on-vsync-and-other-advanced-settings-in-dead-island) just to be safe.

You should be all set. The way this works is that the game apparently reads the settings that you set in this file before it reads the default files. Because this doesn't involve actually modding any of the game's actual data files, you shouldn't be at risk for VAC to flag you for cheating or something.

~[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/k8xll/dead_island_fov_fix/)

Comment: Here's a video tutorial for it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXXacDmEYFc&feature=player_detailpage#t=773s

Comment: nice job finding it, the low FoV was driving me crazy too

Answer (score 2):

If anyone drops by for Linux instructions (like I did), it's the same, except instead of `My Documents\DeadIsland\out\` it uses `~/.steam/steamapps/common/Dead Island/DI/out/`

You can automate the entire process with 2 commands:

```
unzip "~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Dead Island/DI/Data0.pak" Data/Skills/default_levels.xml -d "~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Dead Island/DI/out/"

sed -i 's/CameraDefaultFOV" v="62.5"/CameraDefaultFOV" v="90"/' "~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Dead Island/DI/out/Data/Skills/default_levels.xml"
```

This assumes you're using the default Steam library.